# Woocommerce custom field doesn't show when I import a .CSV

Tags: wordpress, csv, woocommerce

I have Woocommerce on a Wordpress site with some custom fields (already used hooks and Toolset plugin to create them) however when I try to import a .CSV file with products the custom fields don't show and I can't figure out what's missing.

Answer (score -1):

WP All Import plugin solved the problem